# Does Web Crawler Store Cookies?

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am currently creating a script that will force my visitors to register/login after downloading 3 files. I am planning to use cookie to track the # of downloads.

Additionally, I want to prevent content farming from bad web crawler. I don't know if web crawler can also store cookies just like normal visitors so that I can also stop them from downloading my files more than 3 times.

If web crawler who don't support cookies can still download my files more than 3 times, is there any other way to kept track their # of visits?

Comment: Crawlers generally don't store cookies, you can make use of captchas to reduce the download rate from bad crawlers, or simply use Javascript, as crawlers avoid java

Comment: depends on the crawler

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, it there any other way to track them? Tracking them by IP Address will require all visitors who shared internet connection to register after 1 of them has been detected who have already downloaded more than 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is track the bot..

I'm not sure if below code will be accurate, as well useragents can be faked, but this is how I do it for now..

```
//crawler detect
  function crawlerDetect($USER_AGENT) { 

  //array of crwalers and their user agent, format: array('user agent', 'name'),
  $crawlers = array( 
  array('useragen1', 'name1'), 
  array('useragen2', 'name2'), 
  array('useragen3', 'name3'), 
  array('useragen4', 'name4'), //cont..
  );

    foreach ($crawlers as $c) { 

      if (stristr($USER_AGENT, $c[0])) { 
        return($c[1]); 
      } 
    }

    return false; 

  }

  $crawler = crawlerDetect($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

  if (!empty($crawler)) {

    //we have a crawler, do something

  }
```

Then you can handle it as you want, you can change the useragent to sort by ips but that may effect few human visitors..

Comment: I believe this is not a good idea because as what you have said, web crawlers can easily fake the useragent. I hope there's some better than this.

Comment: I have been searching for better options too, but till now this is best I could get. If you don't want web crawlers to be able to download, you can use java, crawlers will not touch that part of the code..

Comment: whew! why I did not thought about this before. Yes, using javascript will do the trick. thanks buddy.